# multi profile css property value using html/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="img">
</div></div>
```

this is my html structure achieve a circle style (with some other effects too) of user profile. If it's static, it's easy and just set the background in .img.

But I'm doing a multi users social network, jst wondering is it correct to replace only the background property and keep using others property of for example my case, img class.

Answer (score 0):

With use of `border-radius` you can make a circle effect with then a `background-image` property to shape it, then adjust the width & height to size you desire, you could even use `background-size: cover` to keep the circle responsive to whatever the image size.

```
<div class="profile-circle"></div>

<style>
    .profile-circle {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #777;
        background-image: url('yourimage-50x50.png');
        background-position: -8px -4px;
        border: 2px solid white;
    }
</stlye>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3akF/)</kbd>: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3akF/

[image: Image of Result]

If you wanted to change it over time, then just replace the `background-image` attribute as you described.,

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="base">
  <div class"inherited">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.base, .inherited{
 margin-top:3px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}

.inherited{
 background-image:url("images/123.jpg");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:950px;
 height:572px;
}
```

This will add the shared properties to both types of `div`, but specific ones only to derived `div`s